# Can void method be defined using dot notation?

Tags: java, object, methods

I've just started learning Java and I am stuck at this MCQ:

Assume class Temp is defined as belowand the statment `Temp a= new temp()` is
successfully executed Which of the statement is illegal in Java?

```
class Temp {
 public static int i;
 public void method1() { }
 public static void method2() { }
}
```

A. System.out.println(i);

B. Temp.method1();

C. a.method1();

D. Temp.method2();

The answer is B, but I can't understand why. Is it because a void method cannot be defined using the dot notation unless it's static?

Comment: `method1` is not static, in other words you have to create a `Temp` class instance before calling this method.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the return type of `void`.  You simply can't call an *instance* method *statically*.

Comment: Are you sure B is the only illegal one? What about A?

Comment: @Henry exactly! I thought the answer is A, the reason being i is not initialized?

Comment: Not because of that, but it should be `System.out.println(Temp.i);`

Comment: @Henry: I guess the difference is that `System.out.println(i);` is correct when beeing called from class Temp (In which case you don't need to add the classname in front of it) but `Temp.method1();` is wrong no matter from where in your code you try to call it.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS that would be an explanation, but on the other hand "class Temp is defined as below" and there is no further code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `method1` is non-static method. You can use methods with class names only if they are static. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details.